# Embeded Youtube 360 video doesn't work in iOS Safari

Tags: ios, wordpress, youtube, safari, 360-degrees

Is there a way to embed a youtube video in a wordpress post that lets the 360 video work?

I made this [test video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZO8-wJs2es), and it works everywhere I've tested so far except when I view it in iOS Safari.

The video plays, but the 360 environment doesn't function at all.

Thanks for any leads in figuring this out.

Comment: YouTube 360 videos are not supported on mobile [yet].

Answer (score 0):

According to Google support, "Safari does not provide the necessary APIs to enable spherical playback to all users at this time."

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/oCk6k38Wdoc